# mysqli vs msql and PDO connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

i am trying to make a basic cms, following the tutorial here:[Cms Tut](https://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/)

In Article.php, he uses the mysql_escape_string($order) with a PDO connection, which now is removed from php 7, i changed to mysqli_escape_string($order) and proceedes somehow but gives the errors with the 2 parameters. I am new to php, but as i searched, i think the problem is with the PDO connection, i cannot put the connection as second argument. Any thoughts and ideas? Thanks in Advance.

Here is the code:

```
public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
   $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
   $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles
           ORDER BY " . mysqli_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

   $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
   $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
   $st->execute();
   $list = array();

   while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
     $article = new Article( $row );
     $list[] = $article;
   }

   // Now get the total number of articles that matched the criteria
   $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
   $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
   $conn = null;
   return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
 }
```

After updating the code, with creating a mysqli connection, in browser there is , this error: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

and in server error log also this: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on boolean

The update code is:

```
public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="publicationDate DESC" ) {
   $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
   $link = mysqli_connect(DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DSN);

   $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate FROM articles
           ORDER BY " . $link->real_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

   $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
   $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
   $st->execute();
   $list = array();

   while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
     $article = new Article( $row );
     $list[] = $article;
   }

   // Now get the total number of articles that matched the criteria
   $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
   $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
   $conn = null;
   return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
 }
```

Comment: You say you get errors, but not what the errors are, nor confirm exactly which statement is erroring. That's pretty much the most key information regarding your problem :-/

Comment: The errors is about the sqli_real_escape_string(), and is about the 2 parameters that has to take.

Comment: Don't *describe* the error. Update yer question and include the exact text. Not a paraphrase of it. The exact text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick **one** of `mysql_`, `mysqli_` and `PDO` (don't pick `mysql_`).

You can't mix `PDO` and `mysqli_`.

You don't need to use `mysqli_escape_string` to defend PDO against SQL injection; it has its own methods (which you are already using for `nubRows`!!).

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for guidance on handling special characters with PDO.

Comment: Can you use parameters for parts of the SQL statement itself? I suspect... no? (re your comment about using params for `numRows` being relevant to a tactic for escaping the other bit too).